# No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7000/swagger/index.html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to set up Swagger for my .Net Core 6 project but I get the below issue:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7000/swagger/index.html
```

[image: Issue]

Below is my **Program.cs** class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using MyWebApp.API.Mappers;
using MyWebApp.Data.DBContext;
using MyWebApp.Data.Mappers;
using MyWebApp.Data.Repositories.Implementation;
using MyWebApp.Domain.Business.Implementation;
using MyWebApp.Domain.Business.Interface;
using MyWebApp.Domain.Repositories.Interface;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyWebAppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAppDbConnection")));
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// AutoMapper
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(
               typeof(RequestResponseMapper).Assembly,
               typeof(DataMapper).Assembly
               );

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITaskService, TaskService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITaskRepository, TaskRepository>();

// Swagger config
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyWebApp", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyWebApp v1");
        c.DisplayOperationId();
        c.DisplayRequestDuration();
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyWebAppDBContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

app.Run();
```

and my **launchsettings.json**:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13145",
      "sslPort": 44344
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MyWebApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7000;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be great.

Comment: are running the application using IIS Express?

Comment: yes, I am running via IIS Express

Comment: have you tried for 5000 port?

Comment: It gives this error on 5000 - The connection for this site is not secure. localhost sent an invalid response.

Comment: can you please add this   "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json", before "iisSettings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was  running in development env,and the related middleware( generate swagger page ) won't be  called,so the page won't be generated,then you got 404 err

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyWebApp v1");
        c.DisplayOperationId();
        c.DisplayRequestDuration();
    });
}
```

it should be

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(.....);
}
```

Comment: Ah! This was indeed a silly mistake from my side. Thank you so much!